# ExcelDataReader.AsDataSet not working

Tags: c#, excel, exceldatareader

I'm using ExcelDataReader v.2.1. library to read both xls and xlsx files in my C# project. This way:

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
IExcelDataReader excelReader;

string extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);

if (extension == ".xls")
{
    excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
}
else if (extension == ".xlsx")
{
    excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
}
else
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Wrong file extension");
}

return excelReader;
```

Then, I use "AsDataSet" method to get a filled DataSet:

```
_dataSet = GetDataReader(_options.Filepath).AsDataSet();
```

It works fine most of the times, but, with some XLSX files, it only reads the first column.
I've been looking at excelReader instance with a Watch and I saw that it actually gets all the values of the Excel, but then, when using the AsDataSet method, it only reads the first column.

Do you know what can be going wrong here? Do you think it could be a "AsDataSet" method bug?

Comment: There are fiew changes to be made with adding reference to ExcelDataReader.Dataset. Here is a guide to add those changes. https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/issues/262#issuecomment-365514084

Answer (score 56):

install ExcelDataReader.DataSet via nugget

Answer (score 5):

```
Install-Package ExcelDataReader.DataSet -Version 3.6.0
```

Install DataSet to work with AsDataSet